# Minimum Path Sum, how to decrease runtime

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, runtime

So recently I did Minimum Path Sum problem from leet code, i came up with the algorithm with my own and it got accepted. Then I saw people have better run time than me but they are using the same logic. Please review this code and give me some tips on how to minimize run time.

```
import sys

class Solution:
    def minPathSum(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        t = [[0 for i in range(len(grid[0]))]for j in range(len(grid))]
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[i])):
                if i==0 and j==0:
                    t[i][j]= grid[i][j]
                elif(i==0):
                    t[i][j] = t[i][j-1]+grid[i][j]
                elif(j==0):
                    t[i][j] = t[i-1][j]+grid[i][j]
                else:
                    t[i][j] = min(t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]) + grid[i][j]
        return t[-1][-1]
```

Comment: Most of the cases i&j  both are > 0. So I suggest you put this as the second condition than last. This will avoid checking i ==0 and j==0 unnecessarily most of the time.

Comment: okay I see, thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without changing the algorithm, you could do the following:

- You don't use `sys`, so the import seems not necessary.
- List initialisation can be done with the `*` operator, like `[0] * len(grid[0])`. This should be faster than list comprehension.
- The `t` matrix holds a lot of data that is never accessed again. At any given moment only the last two rows of `t` are relevant: a current and a previous row. So actually you can gain space and only allocate memory for those two rows, and reuse that space as you iterate. Even more, you can do it with one row only, as the previous row is only needed for reading the value at the current column, while you calculate a new value for the current column. So you may just progressively overwrite the values in a single row, instead of using two rows.
- The special case for `j==0` can be simplified, by prefixing the above mentioned row with one extra value Infinity. That way you can make it that no special case is needed any more for `j==0`. This is because `min(x, Infinity)` will always be *x*.
- A similar trick can be applied for the case `i==0`: just initialise the above mentioned row with infinity values. Then set a starting path-sum value of 0 in that row. So when you process the first grid row, the `min` function will correctly accumulate & sum the values from left to right, which is what you want when `i==0`.
- Use `enumerate` in your loops: that way you get an index and a grid value at the same time.

Here is how the code can look after making those changes:

```
class Solution:
    def minPathSum(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        # You only need a row for this dynamic programming, not a matrix.
        # The first value is an extra Infinity value to make the `j==0`
        #    case just like any other.
        t = [float('inf')] * (len(grid[0]) + 1)
        t[1] = 0  # At the start we have a path-sum of zero
        for row in grid:
            for j, val in enumerate(row):
                # Updates are made from index 1 onwards. 
                # At index 0 we have a static Infinity.
                # t[j+1] is the sum for the path coming from above, and
                # t[j] is the sum for the path coming from the left.
                t[j+1] = min(t[j+1], t[j]) + val
        return t[-1]
```

Comment: this is amazing :)